# my vba code is running very slow. and excel freezes while running

Tags: excel, vba

I have a total of 800 rows. While the code is running, excel freezes and is completed in almost 1 minute. Where do you think this problem arises? Does the same code run fast and smoothly on your computer? Do you have the same problems while the code is running?

```
Sub counterfunc()
 Dim i, counter As Integer
 For i = 2 To Sayfa3.Range("A:A").End(xlDown)

 Sayfa3.Cells(i, "J").Value = Sayfa3.Cells(i, "A").Value
 counter = counter + 1
Next  

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sayfa3.Range("A:A").End(xlDown)`... no, that's not doing what you think it is. But more importantly, why are you looping in the first place?

Comment: `Sayfa3.Range("A:A").End(xlDown)` takes the value of the last populated row before a blank row in A

Comment: [The correct way to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba), [Use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: Also worth noting that `Dim i, counter As Integer` is also not doing what you think it does, assigning a `Variant/Double` variable to `i` by "guessing". Either way, try to get into the habit of using `Long` type variable for loops (when a loop is required) > `Dim i as Long, Counter as Long`

Comment: Why are you even bothering with VBA, this is a simple formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were going to loop, this would get it done:

```
Sub counterfunc()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim LR As Long
 LR = Sayfa3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
 For i = 2 To LR

    Sayfa3.Cells(i, "J").Value = Sayfa3.Cells(i, "A").Value

 Next i

End Sub
```

However, as stated, why loop?  You could simply copy/paste the column (or pastespecial if formatting is an issue)

```
Sub counterfunc2()
    Sayfa3.Columns("A").Copy Sayfa3.Columns("J")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Or rather `Sayfa3.Range("J2:J" & LR).Value = Sayfa3.Range("A2:A" & LR).Value`